# Sqlite Select Into Matrix

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, insert

I'm not really sure how to title this question but I am trying to do the following:

I have data in a table in the following form:

```
id         value      date
--         -----       --------
123        100        2014-08-01
124        101        2014-08-01
234        100.5      2014-08-02
...
```

Its about 100k rows spanning a two week period. What I have been trying to do is create a matrix of sorts where the first column is a unique list of id's that exist in this period, and then to have a column for each date, populating the `value` fields and if there is no value for a particular `id` on a given `date` then fill it with `NULL`.

```
id      2014-08-01    2014-08-02   ...
-----   ----------    ---------    -----
123     100           105
124     101           NULL
...
```

I am using SQLite and my first approach involved creating a temporary table, which I then figured I could just populate. After creating the table and populating the first column with a unique set of `id`'s, I tried the following code (NOTE: I named the columns using a string of their date in my `temp_table`):

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO temp_table ("2014-08-01") SELECT my_table.value
FROM my_table LEFT OUTER JOIN temp_table ON temp_table.id = my_table.id
WHERE my_table.date = '2014-08-01'
```

Unfortunately this appears to simply add new rows to my table instead of replacing into the existing rows that are empty except for their `id`. I have also considered how I might do this with a complex `SELECT` but aside from the joining the table against itself an unacceptable number of times I'm not really sure how that could work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To update rows in place, use UPDATE:

```
UPDATE temp_table
SET "2014-08-01" = (SELECT value
                    FROM my_table
                    WHERE id = temp_table.id
                      AND date = '2014-08-01')
```

You can use multiple UPDATE statements, or write all columns into the same query.
However, it is not possible to loop over the possible columns dynamically.